# Ejecutar un comando en cmd, modificando la cadena mediante textbox

Tags: c#, variables, cmd

buenos dias!

Yo manejo comandos windows, por ejemplo cambiar nombre de equipo, ip, modificar usiarios etc mediante cmd.

Mi pregunta es: como puedo hacer en c# windows form ejecutar un comando cmd pasandole como dato de entrada en un textbox el nombre del pc real y en otro textbox pasarle el nuevo nombre del pc a cambiar?
Ejemplo del codigo.
Wmic useraccount where "nombre='textbox1pcreal'" rename 'textboxnewname'

Podrian ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

prodria ser asi:

```
string PrepareCmd=  "/C " // la "c" se debe agregar siempre al inicio del comando

string StrCmdLine = "echo hello word";// el comando que tu quieras

string CmdExecute = RunCMD+StrCmdLine ;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", CmdExecute);
```